# Convert list of string into a comma separated string using lambda expression query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am attaching my full query in which `ps.productId` is returning list of strings and I want all strings comma separated as a single string like "a,b,c" 
How can I achieve this using lambda expression!

```
ProductIDs = string.Join(",", ps.ProductID),
ProductIDs = string.Join(",", _DataContext.ProductSelectionEntity.Where(x => x.BillingId == bill.Id).Select(x => x.ProductID).ToList())
```

`ps.productIds` will return a `List<string>`, I want it in a string format `"1,2,3,4"`

```
var results = (from uastatus in _DataContext.UaStatusEntity
               where uastatus.IsUaComplete == false
               join client in _DataContext.Client on uastatus.ClientID equals client.ClientID
               where client.ClientStatus == "Active" && 
                     client.IsEnrolledNHCR.HasValue && 
                     client.IsEnrolledNHCR.Value
               join ps in _DataContext.ProductSelectionEntity on bill.ClientId equals ps.ClientID
               where bill.Id == ps.BillingId
               select new PendingUA
                          {
                               ClientId = client.ClientID,
                               ClientRelationship = client.ClientRelationship,
                               ClientName = client.ClientName,
                               EIN = client.EIN,     
                               ProductIDs = string.Join(",", ps.ProductID),
                               ProductIDs = string.Join(",",_DataContext.ProductSelectionEntity.Where(x => x.BillingId == bill.Id).Select(x => x.ProductID).ToList())             
                          }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Error message

Comment: You miss the error message

Comment: You cannot use `string.Join` with EF as it doesn't have a way to translate that into SQL.  Instead pull the list of values, then use an `AsEnumerable` followed by a `Select` where you can then use `string.Join`.

Answer (score 0):

You must extract value from database before use string.Join

```cs
var resultsFromDB = (from uastatus in _DataContext.UaStatusEntity
               where uastatus.IsUaComplete == false
               join client in _DataContext.Client on uastatus.ClientID equals client.ClientID
               where client.ClientStatus == "Active" && 
                     client.IsEnrolledNHCR.HasValue && 
                     client.IsEnrolledNHCR.Value
               join ps in _DataContext.ProductSelectionEntity on bill.ClientId equals ps.ClientID
               where bill.Id == ps.BillingId
               select new 
                          {
                               ClientId = client.ClientID,
                               ClientRelationship = client.ClientRelationship,
                               ClientName = client.ClientName,
                               EIN = client.EIN,     
                               ProductID = ps.ProductID,

                          }).ToList();
var results = (from value in resultsFromDB
              let ProductIDS = string.Join(",", resultsFromDB.Where(x => x.ClientId == value.ClientId ).Select(x => x.ProductID).ToList())
               select new PendingUA
                          {
                               ClientId = value.ClientID,
                               ClientRelationship = value.ClientRelationship,
                               ClientName = value.ClientName,
                               EIN = value.EIN,     
                               ProductIDS = ps.ProductIDS ,

                          }).Distinct().ToList();
```

for better performance, use linq group by

Comment: You could use `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList` for `resultsFromDB` and avoid creating an intermediate list.